# Deploying gradle spring application on a 1and1 cloud server

Tags: spring, apache, tomcat, spring-boot, server

I have an apache/2.4.18 ubuntu server and I want to host my spring application on it. I generated a JAR file and can run it on the server. It starts an embedded tomcat server on port 8090.

However when i navigate to 'my-site-ip:8090' the connection times out.

I have zero experience deploying web applications so any help would be appreciated.

I've created a TCP rule for port 8090 and still no joy.

The solution was adding a proxy to  the Myapp.conf file as below:

```
ProxyRequests off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8090/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8090/

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: So possible issues that you need to sort out. Opening the port from external world. This would be config on your hosting provider. Opening the port on local machine. This would be needed if the machine uses `ufw` or `iptables` firewall. Next would be IP binding. Check if the message you get is listening to `127.0.0.1:8090` or `0.0.0.0:8090` because in the later one only it will work from external connections

Comment: You don't have to use apache, you can just use the embedded tomcat on 8090.

If you want to use apache in front of tomcat, you will need to proxy the embedded tomcat server through apache.

On Centos,  I had problems with permissions, se-linux, and sysctl.
I can post my configuration changes for CentOS if you think it would be helpful.
Are you trying to use tomcat behind apache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It´s very hard to explain all the steps in one answer but you can follow these steps to get into the full configuration by your own. I did the same on my `1&1 cloud server`.

First of all you need root access to your server.

Normally, on your server the port `80` and `443` should already be open. Else you can define that in the `1&1 Admin Portal`. If your Server already has the apache configuration you should be able to see the apache site if you go to your server address. You can find details and the full setup if you dont have an apache installed for this step here:

[How To Install the Apache Web Server on Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-ubuntu-16-04)

The second step would be to configure a `virtual host` on your `apache webserver`.

[image]

This is cool because you can define multiple domains and there applications on your server. So `http://yourServer.com`(port 80 or 443 from extern) goes to `yourApp1`. (port 8090 from intern).

In this step you will tell apache if your enter your `url` to go to your app with port `8090`

[How To Set Up Apache Virtual Hosts on Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04)

The last step would be to install your `spring-boot` app as a service on your machine. The docs of Spring describes it very well.

[Installation as an init.d Service](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-initd-service)

If you install the app as a service you are able to start and stop the app with the `service` command.

```
service myapp start
```

And dont forget to [add the plugin for](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-install) `maven` or `gradle` to your `pom.xml`. This is necessary to run the app as a service.

If you follow these Steps you should be able to reach you app without specify a port and be ready to go with your app in production if necessary.

Comment: Hi Patrick this is really helpful. I'm struggling with the exact method of pointing the url to port 8090. I've created the new .conf file which points to the root of  my app but again it's just displaying the directory containing the .jar file

Comment: @Hughes_J in the cloud control panel under firewall settings you can open some ports. I would not recommend to open to many ports.

Comment: Yeah I have the required ports open, it must be how I'm configuring the proxy in the .conf file.

Comment: I added the .conf file to the original post

Answer (score 1):

The best approach for this would be to use the apache proxy. This should get it done.
https://blog.marcnuri.com/running-apache-tomcat-and-apache-httpd-on-port-80-simultaneously/

Comment: Although not the accepted answer, you contribution helped me with setting up the proxy. Thanks!